# How can I make many samples from a specific population in R?

Tags: r, random

I have this population:

`MyPopulation <- c(1:100)`

and I want to create a data frame of 40 columns and 5 lines. Each column has to be a random sample of `MyPopulation`, so I try this:

```
MySample <- data.frame(NoSample = c(1:5))

for (i in 1:40) {
  MySample$i <- sample(MyPopulation,5)
}
```

The result is a data frame with only 1 more column (named `i`) with a random sample as values.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Study `help("$")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution probably would be

```
MyPopulation <- c(1:100)

MySample <- data.frame(NoSample = c(1:5))

for (i in 1:40) {
  MySample[,i+1] <- sample(MyPopulation,5)
}
```

Comment: Since R is a vectorized schema, suggest avoiding loops whenever possible.

Comment: @L Smeets , thanks a lot! Your code works fine. Now I realize what I was doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign new columns that way, try `MySample[paste(i)] = ...`

That is you cannot assign a numeric value to a column, hence strings.

Comment: thanks a lot! I understand this problem from L Smets' answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `replicate` + `as.data.frame`

```
MySample <- as.data.frame(replicate(40,sample(MyPopulation,5)))
```

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding , thanks a lot! Your code works as I wanted and it's the simplest solution (I think). I accepted L Smets' answer because it was closest to my trying.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a single stream of random values and then state the column dimension in a matrix with the row count being imputed:

```
m <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 200, replace = TRUE), ncol = 40)
df <- as.data.frame(m)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It will be food for thought, because I 'm new in R, so I have no practice with `matrix`.